# OpenVPN: connect to device with duplicate address to local network

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, openvpn, routing

I'm connecting remotely to my office with OpenVPN set up on my (TP Link Omada) router. Works well.

But I have the same IP address range and can't connect to remote devices that have the same address locally. Eg:

- Both networks have DHCP servers issuing addresses on 192.168.0.x
- When connected to VPN, I CAN access the device on eg 192.168.0.105 - I have no such device on my local network
- But the router on both networks is 192.168.0.1 - trying to connect to the remote router just sends me to my own router (and likewise for other matching IPs)

I've tried:

- Different browsers (and curl from the command line) to ensure it's not a browser cached redirect
- Connecting with or without the 'Use this connection only for resources on its network' option
- Adding a static route eg Address 192.168.0.1 / Netmask 255.255.255.255 / Gateway 192.168.0.1
- Adding a static route eg Address 192.168.0.1 / Netmask 255.255.255.0 / Gateway 192.168.0.1
- The above with Gateway set to the remote public IP address

Is there a way round this (other than redefining DHCP ranges on both routers so as not to overlap)? I think it might be to do with metrics but I can't figure out how to make my default/local connection have a higher metric.

Comment: My own experience is that changing the home subnet (to, for example, 192.168.2.1 for the home router) is easy, fast, and a solid permanent fix. Other advantages, too. Don't dismiss it too quickly.